# do not allow user to enter more value if first digit is zero

Tags: javascript, php

i am doing some custom validation on my front end using java script what i want to achieve is if user is entering any digit other than zero it should proceed what ever he enter's after wards but if the user has entered a zero as a first digit it should not allow the user to enter any value after that!! Just the 0 nothing else
there is a functionality over many websites that i saw if they have unwanted characters in an input field they just backspace it dynamically!! like on many payment processing websites on card number field! so in my case if first digit is zero i will backspace everything that comes after that and if not zero then do nothing let it process..something like that i am looking for
 here's the initial code i am working on

```
<?php $numbers_var='REAR_PRICE_'.str_replace(" ","_",$buttonloop[$i]);?>
<input onkeyup="checknumbers('<?php echo $numbers_var?>')" onkeypress='return event.charCode >= 48 && event.charCode <= 57' name="REAR_PRICE_<?php echo str_replace(" ","_",$buttonloop[$i]);?>"style="color: black;width: 100%;" value="<?=$rear?>" type="input"/>
```

and here's the javascript

```
function checknumbers(i){
    if($("input[name="+i+"]").val()=='0'){
        //what to do?
    }
 }
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can do it all in your keypress event

```js
function checknumbers(event) {
  if(event.target.value === '0' || !(event.charCode >= 48 && event.charCode <= 57)) {
    event.preventDefault()
    return false
  }
}
```

```html
<input 
  type="input"
  onkeypress='checknumbers(event)' 
  name="REAR_PRICE_1"
  style="color: black;width: 100%;"
  value=""
/>
```

Comment: o boy!!!! thanks man really appreciate the help!! keep up the good work

Answer (score 1):

Try this..

```
 function checknumbers(i){
       var input = $("input[name="+i+"]").val();
       if(input == "0"){
          return false;
        }

    }
```

Comment: nops! our return false is not working it is not doing anything moreover i dont need an else

Answer (score 1):

Make it readonly

```
function checknumbers(i){
    if($("input[name="+i+"]").val()=='0'){
       $("#fieldName").prop("readonly", true);
    }
 }
```

Comment: that did the most part but the issue is he can go backspace and enter some other value!!! the thing is in this case if attribute read only is applied he cannot backspace or do anything to it

Comment: i did have a look